# Three.js - I want to make my 3d model of ireland clickable in a certain place

Tags: model, 3d, three.js

Here is my code

Any ideas people?

```
<script>
    var scene, camera, renderer;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
        renderer.setSize(800, 900);
        document.getElementById("mapofireland").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, 600 / 700, 5, 500);
        camera.position.set(1,24,15);
        scene.add(camera);

        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            var WIDTH = window.innerWidth, HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            renderer.setSize(800, 900);
            camera.aspect = 600 / 700;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        });

        renderer.setClearColorHex(0x000000, 0);

        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
        light.position.set(-100,200,100);
        scene.add(light);

        //var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        // directionalLight.position.set(10, 1, 1).normalize();
        //scene.add(directionalLight);

        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load( "models/mapwithmountains.js", function(geometry, materials){

            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('maps/Ireland_map.jpg')
            });
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add(mesh);
        });

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    }

    function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
        projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( geometry );

        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

            intersects[ 0 ].geometry.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

            var particle = new THREE.Sprite( particleMaterial );
            particle.position = intersects[ 0 ].point;
            particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 16;
            scene.add( particle );
        }

        /*
        // Parse all the faces
        for ( var i in intersects ) {

            intersects[ i ].face.material[ 0 ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff | 0x80000000 );
        }
        */
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        controls.update();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's great that you've posted some code, but you should probably state what the issue is. You want to make something clickable, but what have you tried so far and what are the issues with what you have tried?
Also remember to check your post, if formatting of the code looks ok, before you post a question next time...

Comment: I want to make a part of the map clickable so to show some information

Comment: And what have you tried so far? And what are your issues?

Comment: i have tried the mouse down function but nothing seem to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code snippet, the mousedown eventlistener is missing, include the following line in your code for mousedown event..

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown',
        function(e) {
            onDocumentMouseDown(e);
        },
        false);
```